# how to remove certain text in column in R

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to remove certain text from my data using R.

I have a column which contain html language like 'S' and I am trying to remove those.

I tried with below code and got the error.

```
df1 <- removeWords(df, '<root><header><nt>S</nt><rd>')
```

The error message says

```
 Error in UseMethod("removeWords", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'removeWords' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

I am not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: Did you mean to pass a data frame column as the first argument, not a data frame itself?

Comment: No, I want it as a data frame

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the 'tm' package, the first argument to removeWords() should be a "character or text document." You're passing it a dataframe, which is not the class the function expects. A character vector within a dataframe seems to work as the first parameter.

```
df = data.frame(col1 = c("hello", "world"))
df$col1 <- as.character(df$col1)

removeWords(df$col1, "hello")

[1] ""      "world"
```